# How many spanning subgraph of a graph G

Tags: graph-theory

If I have a graph $\mathbb G$ with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges and $c$ components, how can I count how many spanning subgraphs it has?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean spanning subgraphs or spanning forests? If subgraphs, then the answer only dependends on $m$, namely $2^m$.

Comment: I mean spanning subgraphs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subgraph has to contain all of the vertices. Then decide for each edge whether it belongs to the subgraph or not, giving $2^m$ possibilities.

Comment: What confuses me is that there are $c$ components in the graph. Do I have to take also that into account?

Comment: @user127948: Not if the spanning subgraph just means a subgraph whose vertex set is the same as the vertex set of $G$.

Comment: so up to isomorphism it is $2^m$

Answer (score 0):

we have m edges. And by definition of Spanning subgraph of a graph G is a subgraph obtained by edge deletion only. If we make subsets of edges by deleting one edge, two edge, three edge and so on. As there are m edges so there are 2^m subsets. Hence G has 2^m spanning subgraphs.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How is that different from the answer that was posted and accepted six years ago?